# Cake php auth login response

Tags: cakephp, authentication

```
public function login() {

        //if already logged-in, redirect
        if($this->Session->check('Auth.User')){
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages','action' => 'index'));      
        }

        // if we get the post information, try to authenticate
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $status = $this->Auth->user['status'];
                if($status != 0){
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Welcome, '. $this->Auth->user('username')));
                    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'pages','action' => 'index'));
                }else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user is not active'));
                }
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password'));
            }
        } 
    }
```

why I use this function for login . At first time I login with status 1 the system report user is not active but I login at second time with status 1 ok .

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
$status = $this->Auth->user['status'];
```

to

```
$status = $this->Auth->user('status');
```

`user` is a function in `AuthComponent`

If you want to only log users with `status = 1`, you can also try to use the [scope](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)

example:

```
public $components = array(
'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate' => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'scope' => array('status' => '1')
        ),

    )
),
```

);